# App Engine - Java AppStats - It shows all requests as cpu time of 0

Tags: java, google-app-engine, appstats

All lines in my AppStats look like this: `real=19ms cpu=0ms api=0ms overhead=0ms`, it has the correct real time, but the other values are always 0.  Anyone have this problem before or know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running on the local development server, or in production?

Comment: @Nick Both local and production show up like this.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that since the information it *is* showing is the same as is available in logs even when AppStats isn't set up, that you've got the Administrative Interface installed ok, but not the [filter](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html).

Comment: it still shows the real time each individual db call takes within the request, just not cpu_time

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web.xml is setup like below. Working example [here](http://github.com/tleese22/jappstart/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>appstats</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logMessage</param-name>
        <param-value>Appstats available: /appstats/details?time={ID}</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>appstats</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>appstatsConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>appstatsCollection</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```